# How to derive the alternate forms of Power Series Expansion for Modified Bessel Functions of the second kind?

Tags: power-series, special-functions, approximation

I was reading  page 25 of [this document](http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf). They present a strange form of the series expansion of the Modified Bessel Function of the second kind. But I do not know how can the author get this form ?
${K_1}(x) = {\left( {\frac{\pi }{{2x}}} \right)^{1/2}}{e^{ - x}}\left[ {1 + \frac{3}{{8x}}\left( {1 - \frac{5}{{2(8x)}}\left( {1 - \frac{{21}}{{3(8x)}}} \right)} \right)} \right]$.
[image]
I myself observed that (subjectively) using only the first term provide a pretty good approximation.

My problem is to try to use this form to approximate ${K_1}(2\sqrt x )$.

Please help me with this.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression$${K_1}(x) = {\left( {\frac{\pi }{{2x}}} \right)^{1/2}}{e^{ - x}}\left[ {1 + \frac{3}{{8x}}\left( {1 - \frac{5}{{2(8x)}}\left( {1 - \frac{{21}}{{3(8x)}}} \right)} \right)} \right]$$ is nothing else than the Horner method.

SInce you use Mathematica, ask for the series expansion of $K_1(x)$ for infinitely large values of $x$. After factoring and simplifying, you have
$${K_1}(x) = {\left( {\frac{\pi }{{2x}}} \right)^{1/2}}{e^{ - x}}\left[1+\frac{3}{8 x}-\frac{15}{128 x^2}+\frac{105}{1024 x^3}-\frac{4725}{32768
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\right]$$ For the expression inside backets, let $t=\frac 1{8x}$ to make
$$1+3 t-\frac{15 t^2}{2}+\frac{105 t^3}{2}-\frac{4725 t^4}{8}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ which is
$$1+3t\left(1-\frac 5 2t(1-7t(1+   \cdots\right)$$

S0 for your case
$${K_1}(2\sqrt x )=\frac 12 {\left( {\frac{\pi }{{\sqrt x}}} \right)^{1/2}}e^{-2 \sqrt{x}}\left[1+3 t-\frac{15 t^2}{2}+\frac{105 t^3}{2}-\frac{4725 t^4}{8}+O(t^5)\right]$$ with $t=\frac 1{16\sqrt x}$.

Now use Horner's method to write the polynomial it $t$.
$$1+t \left(t \left(\left(\frac{105}{2}-\frac{4725 t}{8}\right)
   t-\frac{15}{2}\right)+3\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I have a question: if this Series Expansion is for $x = \infty$, why does it fit so well when x is small ? thank you very much !